# How do I add a backround image to each DetailViewControllers separately?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I want to build an app that has 5 cells in a `UITableView`. I assigned a background image to the main page of the table view; however, I want to assign different background images to each view that comes up after I tap on a cell. How do I achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array which contains five different images that you want to set as a background. Then you can use didSelect function of UITableViewDelegate and get the selected index. With this index you can get the image and set as background.

```
// do not forget to set delegate for tableview inside your viewcontroller
tableView.delegate = self
```

**Swift**

```
let images = [image1, image3, image3, image4, image5]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedIndex = indexPath.row
    let backgroundImage = images[selectedIndex]
    YOUR_IMAGE_VIEW.image = backgroundImage
}
```

**Objective-C**

```
NSArray *images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, nil];

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    int selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
    UIImage *backgroundImage = images[selectedIndex];
    YOUR_IMAGE_VIEW.image = backgroundImage;
}
```